# Float to currency in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, number-formatting

If a number (float) is input such as 12500, the number is converted to money format as 12,500.00. The format will be '###,###,###.##'. How to do this using java and **without** any apache utils or similar libraries. A comma will repeat after each 3 digits, and the decimal number will be rounded and shown as 2 digits after decimal places. If .5 it should be .50 and
if .569 it should be .57. Is there any solution to this problem through regular expression or anything?

Comment: A float can never represent currency.  If your software accepts a float as a parameter with the intention to convert it to currency, it is already a bug.

Comment: `float` should not be used for currency (or for most things) as it has very poor precision.  I suggest you use `double`, `long` cents or `BigDecimal`

Answer (score 4):

I found following code by doing little bit of search on Google... Might be helpful for you...

Check this link, it is quite helpful to understand. At this link only they have given the way to requisite format...

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberFormat.html

```
static public void displayCurrency( Locale currentLocale) {

    Double currencyAmount = new Double(9876543.21);
    Currency currentCurrency = Currency.getInstance(currentLocale);
    NumberFormat currencyFormatter = 
        NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(currentLocale);

    System.out.println(
        currentLocale.getDisplayName() + ", " +
        currentCurrency.getDisplayName() + ": " +
        currencyFormatter.format(currencyAmount));
}
```

The output generated by the preceding lines of code is as follows:

```
French (France), Euro: 9 876 543,21 €
German (Germany), Euro: 9.876.543,21 €
English (United States), US Dollar: $9,876,543.21
```

In this case you can choose the locale and can enjoy without even knowing the format used in the specific country/place.

Comment: He is asking for the format which have first comma after 2 digit and then 3 for all remaining start from left side.

Comment: He has provided the currency format, but using this code he does not even need to care about currency format. He must not care/research about currency format as sun team has already put efforts to find those formats. :)

Comment: I would use `double` rather than `Double`

Answer (score 2):

```
      public static void main(String args[])
      {
      float amount =  2192.05f;
      NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###.##");
       System.out.println("The Decimal Value is:"+formatter.format(amount));
      }
```

Comment: How does this solution give a comma after every 3 digit? Did you read the question correctly? Also, your code won't compile.

Comment: @BhavikShah.. Why have you used typecasting unnecessarily. Just use `float` value on RHS.