# Formatting an integer to insert a character at specified place

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

I want to format an integer in such a way that if no. of digits are more than 3, a comma should be inserted at 4th location from right and if no. of digits are more than 6, a comma should be inserted at 4th and 7th location from right i.e.

123 should become 123
1234 should become 1,234
12345 should become 12,345
123456 should become 123,456
1234567 should become 1,234,567

I found similar question on SO and on internet but none helped me resolve this problem.

I know this will lead to `String.format(format,arguments)` but I'm unable to specify the 1st parameter i.e. `format`.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: look at this it is a possible duplicate of your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283472/float-to-currency-in-java/13283521

Comment: Use Formatter, [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**DecimalFormat**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to format your integer that way: -

```
int num = 1234567;
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
System.out.println("The value is: " + formatter.format(num));
```

**OUTPUT**: -

```
The value is: 1,234,567
```

Comment: `NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###");` is working

Comment: @GAMA.. Yeah that would also work, but it is really not needed. Go with this one.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DecimalFormat` to format your input string

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
        int d = 1234;
        System.out.println(format.format(d));
```